# fixing index value in dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x

for below code in python:

```
for ts in src_client.time_series.list(limit=1):
    
    new_entry = pd.DataFrame( columns = [ts.name, ts.external_id], index = [ts.id])
```

I get new_entry as:

```
     Ankit      111234
21    Nan        Nan
```

and for this code

```
for ts in src_client.time_series.list(limit=2):
    
    new_entry = pd.DataFrame( columns = [ts.name, ts.external_id], index = [ts.id])
```

I get

```
     AnkitRoger      111234445443
21    Nan              Nan
```

What is happening is I am getting all the values in one line if I am increasing the limit. How can I fix this? I just want all the name and external_id and put it in some excel row to be read later?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `src_client.time_series.list(limit=2)` works a litle different, than you expect.  I think that it returns `iterator` over 2 rows. So you have 2 cycles, and in each of them you process only one row.

```py
ts_out = []
for ts in src_client.time_series.list(limit=2):
    
    new_entry = pd.DataFrame( columns = [ts.name, ts.external_id], index = [ts.id])
    ts_out += [new_entry]

print(ts_out)
```

**Ilustrative output:**

```py
[ DataFrame(1x2)(
     Ankit      111234
21    Nan        Nan
),
DataFrame(1x2)(
     AnkitRoger      111234445443
21    Nan              Nan
)
```